# How to format a date using StringBuilder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, format, stringbuilder

I'm trying to export my data pro Excel using ASP. NET MVC 4, but the fields are not formatted like to know how do I format the date type fields

Below the line of my Append:

```
sb.Append("<td><font face=Arial size=" + "14px" + ">" + dr.dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento.ToString() + "</font></td>");
```

Comment: Try taking a look at AppendFormat( ), by doing concatenations inside your sb.Append you're undoing the good you're doing by using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good reference page [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

It obviously depends on the format you want. But as an example:

```
sb.Append(dr.dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

If you're in doubt as to the format to use I'd suggest trying the ISO 8601 format

```
.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

Comment: I tried to do as the above example but it is giving the following error: formatting DateTime error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments" could help me please

Comment: What is dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento? It's not nullable is it? There should be 4 overloads to DateTime.ToString() one of which takes a format string.

Comment: My dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento is DateTime?

Comment: You want this overload http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is that "DateTime?" as in a nullable DateTime or punctuation? If it's nullable you'll have to access the .Value and provide an alternative if it is null

Comment: that's it! worked! Thank You!  sb.AppendFormat("<td><font face=Arial size=" + "14px" + ">" + "{0}" + "</font></td>", dr.dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento.ToString() == "" ? "" : dr.dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

Comment: Great, two things to look at to make your code safer/more efficient 1) You're still doing some concats with the + symbol in there 2) if your DateTime is null that'll throw. You need to do something like myDate.HasValue ? myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyy") : string.Empty  Glad you've got it working